# Is there a carousel that stops being carousel on small screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I need to add a carousel on web site that shows various number of slides depending on screen width e.g. if the screen is 1920px width it will show 7 items, if width is 980px - 4 items etc. I guess there are plenty of jquery plugins which can do that. One more thing though - when sreen width is small and it can contain only one item -  I need the carousel to stop being a carousel and just stack items one under another. What is better way to do that?

Comment: Please post your html and css of what you have so far

Comment: Look at responsive carousels

Comment: @R4nc1d I actually hoped you could suggest particular carousel that behaves just like I described. There are hundreds of them out there.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
/* do stuff for big screens*/
   .small-screen-carousel{
        display:none;
   }
   .big-screen-carousel{
        display:block;
   }

}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
/* do stuff for medium screens*/
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 80px) and (max-width: 479px) {
/* do stuff for samll screens*/

    .small-screen-carousel{
        display:block;
    }
    .big-screen-carousel{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem and I changed plugin and used elastislide it is exactly works like what you need http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/12/elastislide-responsive-carousel/

Comment: I'm going to give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: For static and dynamic purpose it will be easy to use @dKab